# Connecting to SQL Server using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-sql-developer

I am using oracle sql developer to manage my oracle database. I recently added third party database jdbc drivers to be able to connect to my new MySQL and SQL Server installations. I need help with the right settings for the SQL Server connection i.e UserName, Host Name, Port including formats

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I followed [these](http://kentgraziano.com/2013/01/14/tech-tip-connect-to-sql-server-using-oracle-sql-developer/) instructions to add the jTDS Java library to Oracle SQL Developer. Basically it's about downloading the jTDS zip, unzipping it in some place you can reach later and then add the jTDS.jar as a JDBC third party driver in SQL Developer ((*In the main menu*) Tools > Preferences > (*On the tree menu in the new window*) Database > Third party JDBC drivers > Click on 'Add entry')

I was then able to use my credentials to connect to a SQL Server instance/database using the following connection details. I'm currently using Oracle Developer 4.0.1.14.

[image: Oracle SQL Developer - SQL Server Connection]

The default port for SQL Server instance is 1433, however your SQL Server instance may be running on a non default port. The following site has different methods to determine the port.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2495/identify-sql-server-tcp-ip-port-being-used/

Comment: How would I connect to a SQL Server that is a named instance?  For example, my jTDS connection string elsewhere would be: MYHOSTNAME:1433/MYPRODDB;instance=MYINSTANCE

Comment: You determine the port of the named instance and use that instead of the default 1433. The actually name of the named instance is not used within the connection from SQL Developer.

Comment: How I could connect to a local instance? Like start a new database from scrath

Comment: Connecting to a local instance would have the same requirements as a remote instance. Specify the local IP/hostname and the SQL Server port number. As for starting a new database, I'm assuming you're referring to creating a new database. You can login to SQL Server as the sa account with the master database and create a database using the "create database" statement.

Comment: @hooinator It's now the year 2020... Is this driver from 2013 still the correct route?  All google searches related to accessing SQL Server from Oracle SQL Developer still seem to refer/link back to this driver which was last updated in 2013.  Latest version here 1.3.1: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.3.1/

Comment: Just so people don't lose time like me, you have to know that SQL Developer won't handle T-SQL scripts, just regular queries.

Answer (score 9):

For a named instance, under port use "1433;instance=INSTANCENAME".  Adjust port number accordingly.

Comment: This is sooooo underappreciated answer! There is no documentation at all regarding this feature of port input field...

Comment: There has been a detailed description of use of the connection strings (at least to MS SQL) since the beginning of the year for the latest JDBC Driver. I have not looked for older versions....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url